# Unreachable code and verification

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am (very) new to C# and trying to take in a list of strings from a .txt file and create a top 20 of the most common ones which I want to display. This is for a project, I'm not going to lie but I can't figure it out why I can't reach a certain part of the code and would appreciate any help.

My code so far is:

```
// I have used framework 4  
public class Program
{

    private static int Compare(KeyValuePair<string, int> kv1, KeyValuePair<string, int> kv2)
    {
        return kv2.Value == kv1.Value ? kv1.Key.CompareTo(kv2.Key) : kv2.Value - kv1.Value;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        {
            try
            {
                Dictionary<string, int> histogram = new Dictionary<string, int>();      // creates a dictionary from the text file
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("tweets.txt"))        //reads the text file specified
                {
                    string difline;
                    while ((difline = reader.ReadLine()) != null)       //continues until no lines left
                    {
                        if (histogram.ContainsKey(difline))     //counts specific strings
                            ++histogram[difline];
                        else
                            histogram.Add(difline, 1);
                    }
                }


                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("tweets.txt"))        // Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file.
                // also closes the StreamReader.
                {
                    string line;
                    long linecount = linesinfile("tweets.txt");
                    Console.WriteLine(linecount);
                    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("tweets.html"); //create a writer
                    tw.WriteLine("<html> <body>");
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) // Read and display lines from the file until the end of the file is reached.
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                        tw.WriteLine("{0} <br />", line); //write the lines of text to the html file

                    }
                    tw.WriteLine("</html> </body>");
                    tw.Close(); //close the writer
                }

            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:"); // Let the user know what went wrong.
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            Console.Write("\nPress any key to continue . . . ");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }


    static long linesinfile(string l)
    {
        long count = 0;
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(l))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)       //counts lines until last line
            {
                if (line.StartsWith("#") & line.Length > 1)       //only count lines which start with #
                {
                    count++;    //increases the count
                }
            }
            return count;       //displays the line count
        }

        //this code is unreachable

        Dictionary<string, int> histogram = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("tweets.txt"))
        {
            string line;

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (histogram.ContainsKey(line))
                    ++histogram[line];
                else
                    histogram.Add(line, 1);
            }
            {
                Console.Write("{0} ", histogram);
            }
        }

        List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> sortedHistogram = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>(histogram);
        sortedHistogram.Sort(Compare);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kv in sortedHistogram)
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", kv.Value, kv.Key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you think it would make our lives easier to know which point your code doesn't reach?

Comment: @Patrick87 The "**//this code is unreachable**" line, I'm guessing?

Comment: I have commented with a line which states that **this line is unreachable**

Comment: Awww, the formatting (or lack thereof) hurts my brain.

Comment: Now, how about indenting your code so we can actually see where methods start and end?

Comment: I don't apologise for being new to this. I am sure that we all started somewhere hey?

Comment: @user1150442 No need to apologise for being new, getting the formatting wrong in the first question is also excusable. But for future questions, do yourself and us a favour and learn how to format code properly on SO. Use spaces for indentation, not tabs; indent each scope farther than the enclosing (four spaces per level is a good choice).

Answer (score 3):

A `return` statement stops execution of the current method and returns control to the caller. In your case, you appear to have a premature `return count;` statement in your `linesinfile` method. Try moving the `return count;` to the *end* of the `linesinfile` method, just before the closing `}`, and it should work.

Comment: Thank you Douglas. I have moved the line like you have suggested but the code still doesn't produce the result I wanted. There is still no return of the 'top 20'

Answer (score 3):

this code

```
return count;       //displays the line count
```

is executed unconditionally which in turn means that it ends the execution of the method... this leads to the rest of the code in that method being unreachable.

Answer (score 2):

```
static long linesinfile(string l)
        {
            long count = 0;
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(l))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)       //counts lines until last line
                {
                    if (line.StartsWith("#") & line.Length > 1)       //only count lines which start with #
                    {
                        count++;    //increases the count
                    }
                }
                return count;       //displays the line count
            }
```

In your function you do an unconditional `return count` so rest of the code in this function is typically unreachable.

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains a lot of redundancy. I’ve tried to trim it down and display the top 20 results to console (eliminating the HTML file output).

```
// I have used framework 4  

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    private static int Compare(KeyValuePair<string, int> kv1, KeyValuePair<string, int> kv2)
    {
        return kv2.Value.CompareTo(kv1.Value);   // descending order
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            int linecount = 0;
            Dictionary<string, int> histogram = new Dictionary<string, int>();      // creates a dictionary from the text file
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("tweets.txt"))        //reads the text file specified
            {
                string difline;
                while ((difline = reader.ReadLine()) != null)       //continues until no lines left
                {                   
                    linecount++;    //increases the count

                    if (histogram.ContainsKey(difline))     //counts specific strings
                        ++histogram[difline];
                    else
                        histogram.Add(difline, 1);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Line count: " + linecount);

            Console.WriteLine("Top 20:");
            List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> sortedHistogram = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>(histogram);
            sortedHistogram.Sort(Compare);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kv in sortedHistogram.Take(20))
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", kv.Value, kv.Key);
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:"); // Let the user know what went wrong.
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        Console.Write("\nPress any key to continue . . . ");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: A bit of redundancy, it's down to half lol. Thank you so much, I can put the wine bottle down now.